# Why C++20 format has no strong typedef for format string?

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

C++20 introduces the following [format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) function (locale and wstring_view versions ignored since they do not affect the question):

```
template<class... Args>
std::string format(std::string_view fmt, const Args&... args);
```

There is nothing wrong with this, but I wonder why is there not an overload that accepts a "strong typedef", something like

```
template<class... Args>
    std::string format(std::format_string fmt, const Args&... args);
```

My guesses would be some or all of the following:

1. increased complexity of implementation
2. increased compilation time
3. code bloat

, but I wonder if this was ever discussed during standardization.

Comment: Do you mean something like the compile-time argument validity checks you can perform in the `fmt` library?

Comment: @NathanPierson no, something like this: void f(string_view fmt, string_view name)/*calls format with arguments*/; ... f("Bob", "Hi, {}");// oops, wrong order

Comment: Is that a bug that happens? I've never seen a format string mistakenly put out of order.

Comment: What would your strong typedef be of and how would it help?

Comment: Since `"Bob"` would surely be a valid `format_string` under your proposal and `"Hi, {}"` is a valid `std::string`, the only way I could see this working is if you _disable_ the first overload and force people to cast their format strings to `std::format_string` to call `format`. I suppose you could argue that it should be an error to call `std::format` with more args than the format string accepts, but that would still be a _runtime_ error under typical usage scenarios.

Comment: @NathanPierson "and force people to cast their format strings" - there is no need to force any cast, people can use format_string as a normal variable, like people are not forced to cast ints to chrono::seconds before using chrono...

Comment: So what, exactly, would prevent `"Bob"` from being converted to a `std::format_string` in such a way that `std::format("Bob", "Hi, {}")` is disallowed?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl If `format_string` is implicitly generated from a string, then what safety does adding this give you?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*there is no need to force any cast, people can use format_string as a normal variable*" Then they'd have to cast them *then*.

Comment: @NathanPierson explicit constructor

Comment: @NicolBolas I think we are not talking about same thing. Can you provide example of problem you see?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: If you have a string that you need to use as a format string, then you have to turn it into a format string because it *wasn't one before now*. Hence the cast.

Comment: @NicolBolas I Ah I would consider that construction, not a cast, that is why I was consused...  e.g. you could do  format_string fs("Hello {});  or format_string fs(LoadFmtStringFromFile());

Comment: If you're relying on explicit constructors to prevent `std::format("Bob", "Hi, {}")` from being called, that means you're disabling the overload of `std::format` that takes an `std::string_view` as its first argument. At which point _neither_ `std::format("Bob", "Hi, {}")` _nor_ `std::format("Hi, {}", "Bob")` is a valid call because neither one has a `std::format_string` as the first argument. But if you'd actually stored them in variables `std::format_string fs("Hello {}"); std::string name("Bob"); std::format(name, fs)` wouldn't work?

Comment: @NathanPierson "If you're relying on explicit constructors to prevent std::format("Bob", "Hi, {}") from being called, that means you're disabling the overload of std::format that takes an std::string_view as its first argument" that was not my intention . My question is about optin(string_view version still exists), not about forcing people to not use string_view for their format strings.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: But you stated that the reason you wanted this is to prevent the code you posted from compiling. What you've suggested wouldn't do that. So we're back to the first question: why do you want this? Why do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to enable users to be able to avoid code like that compiling in their code(if they enforce use of format_string). I am perfectly happy that format keeps on working for people who do not want to use strong types. Same as boost::units std::chrono do not prevent people who do not want to use them from using ints  :)

Comment: If your goal isn't to prevent `std::format("Bob", "Hello, {}")` from compiling, it's quite difficult to see what this actually does. If the problem is you have functions of your own that currently have signature `foo(std::string, std::string)` and you want to rewrite them as `foo(format_string, std::string)` to try to enforce order, you can write your own thin wrapper around `std::string`.

Comment: @NathanPierson: "*I want to enable users to be able to avoid code like that compiling in their code(if they enforce use of format_string).*" But what you're suggesting *wouldn't do that* because none of those are `format_string`s. They're string literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of strong typedefs is to prevent this from working:

```cpp
void takes_id(SomeIdType);
takes_id(42);
```

The point of `format` is to allow this to work:

```cpp
format("User {} owes me {} points.", name, 100);
```

That is a string literal. Requiring a strong type means more burden on the users, having to write something like this:

```cpp
format(format_string("User {} owes me {} points."), name, 100);
```

This isn't a burden on the typical strong typedef use case, since you will actually be trafficking in `SomeIdType`s. You'll have a function that gives you a `SomeIdType`, you'll store a member of type `SomeIdType`. Basically, the amount of actual conversions will be fairly minimal... so on the call site you would just write `takes_id(my_id)` and the code mostly just looks the same, with added safety.

But the overwhelmingly common case for formatting is to use string literals, so that's a lot of added annotation.

The nominal benefit of strong typing is to catch users doing maybe something like this:

```cpp
format(name, "User {} owes me {} points.", 100);
```

Or even:

```cpp
format(name, 100);
```

The former seems unlikely to ever happen. The latter is certainly possible, if the first argument happens to be sufficiently string-like. But is this a sufficiently common problem as to force everyone to write more code? I don't think so.

Now, if string literals had their own distinct type from `const char[N]` (and I really wish they did), then it would be possible to create a type that is implicitly constructible from `std::string_literal` but needs to be *explicitly* constructed from `std::string_view`. And if that were a thing, then the API probably would've used that - since this would require no annotation in the common case and not using string literals seems sufficiently rare that requiring an explicit cast seems... fine?

Besides, on the question of safety, the issue isn't so much passing the wrong kind of string as actually being able to verify the value of it in its context:

```cpp
format("User {} owes me {} points.", name);
```

We'd really like for this *not to compile*, even though we provided a format string in the correct spot. And it appears to be [possible to do this](https://twitter.com/vzverovich/status/1328346179797544967). But we don't need strong typedefs for this either, we just need the ability to know if the format string is a constant expression or not.

---

To summarize, the answer to:

> but I wonder why is there not an overload that accepts a "strong typedef"

is that this requires users to provide more call-side annotation while providing very minimal benefit. It would only catch wrong uses in the rarest of uses, so seems like a fairly bad trade-off.

Comment: nice answer, but just to clarify since my q is probably not clear enough on this: I do not want to remove string_view overload, I just wonder why format_string overload does not exist.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl If the format_string overload did exist, it wouldn't prevent anyone from calling the string_view overload.

Comment: Tried to get the super nice twitter link godboltified, not sure if I fail with macro defines, or godbolt version of "trunk" is too old... https://godbolt.org/z/jxPfhz https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=VERSION

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I asked you way at the beginning if you meant the compile-time time argument validity checks you can perform in the `fmt` library and you said no, you were talking about something different. And observe the limitations of those checks: https://godbolt.org/z/bd5oxc this is perfectly happy to compile even though there's obviously no way to know at compile time that `fmt_string` will be valid.

Comment: @NathanPierson I was replying to link Barry provided in his answer... it is not directly  related to the question.

Comment: You could certainly allow `const char[N]` (for any `N` but require, say, `const char*` and `std::string_view` to be explicitly converted.  The possibility of using a (const!) character array as a format string when you meant to use it as a value is surely sufficiently remote as to be ignored.